# CEDET in emacs (command line mode)

Tags: emacs, terminal, elisp, command-line-interface, cedet

I'm trying to setup and android development on my mac using Emacs and CEDET (I hate Eclipse, and I want to keep using emacs, but I want the auto-completion, so this setup seemed perfect).

However, I want to use emacs in the terminal. I have a problem with the auto-completion. CEDET is trying to use the graphical menu "popup-menu" and I got an error in CLI mode: "Symbol's function definition is void: popup-menu", which makes perfect sense.

My question is, is there any way to use Emacs' termcap menu for CEDET auto-completion?

Thanks!

Thibault.

Edit: you can find my emacs configuration there: https://github.com/tbronchain/emacs

Edit2: here are some screenshots showing 1- What is the CEDET auto-completion in GUI mode 2- the menu I would like to use for CEDET in CLI mode

CEDET = http://bit.ly/1iptfq3
auto-complete = http://bit.ly/1kZVDz9

Comment: I recommend you report this via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Oh, wait, I think I misunderstood; the problem is probably in *auto-complete* which is not part of Emacs.

Comment: Indeed, my problem isn't really a bug. I think CEDET auto completion isn't compatible with CLI emacs (is it?), so I would like to trick it and use the standard auto-completion menu instead. I wanted to know if anyone faced it before (am I the only one trying to do some android development on emacs with a good old terminal? I guess no ... and I guess everyone would like to get the auto-completion for big API class names ...)

Comment: I think `auto-complete + yasnippet + cscope + etag` is better than `CEDET`. `CEDET` is so slowly..

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "auto completion".

Comment: @Stefan I have uploaded some screenshots which illustrates what I'm talking about (see the original post). The CEDET screenshot is in GUI mode, the other one is the "auto-complete" package in CLI mode. I'd like to use the menu from auto-complete with CEDET, in CLI mode.

Comment: @JerryZhang Thanks Jerry, I will definitely have a look at this!

Comment: Hey, @Stefan. I know what you mean. I really didn't answer this question immediately. I just suggest @tbronchain to try those plugins( `auto-complete + ya...` ), because I had use ECB before, I also used [clang](https://github.com/brianjcj/auto-complete-clang) . I like keep emacs configure file simply and efficiency.

Comment: @JerryZhang I had a look about these tools, they're cool and deserve a try. However, I haven't found any which does what CEDET does: search in the external library for methods auto-completion. To be honest, I don't want to have to copy manually the long API method names ... (cd this screenshot http://bit.ly/1iptfq3)

Comment: @Stefan I know they are different tool before I first comment ... OK, I' am wrong, I admit my answer is misleading ... I just want to recommend those tool for C/C++ develop.

Comment: You might also like to try `company-mode`: it's similar to auto-complete and comes with a Semantic backend, so it can use CEDET.

Comment: @Stefan Will have a look at this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer!

I didn't succeed to replace the menu by auto-complete, however, it works perfectly with company! It is a little bit more messy than the GUI menu, but it's still awesome!

Thanks to @Stefan for helping with this!

I will post my full configuration on github when I'll be done with this configuration (I'm trying to optimise the keyboard shortcuts a bit).

Cheers,